# How to detect which button is clicked in a Javascript for loop?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, dom, addeventlistener

I made a loop generating 15 "levels" for my project. How could I detect which of these 15 buttons is clicked specifically so I can load the appropriate level (load level 1 when first button is clicked, level 2 when second button is clicked, etc.)? Thanks!

```
function loadLevels(){
    for (var i = 1; i < 16; i ++){
        var btn = document.createElement("button");
        var lvlNumber = document.createTextNode(i);
        btn.appendChild(lvlNumber);
        document.body.appendChild(btn); 
        btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
            startedLevel(i);
        });
    } 
}
```

Comment: `for (let i` will fix this - you should use `let` and `const` instead of `var` in modern javascript - unless you specifically want the "side-effects" of using `var` :p

Comment: var is used only for scope, as @JaromandaX said use let will fix your problem

Comment: by the way, old school (pre ES6) - you would use an IIFE, or just a function to add the event listener etc that you call with btn and i as arguments

Comment: It worked, thanks! So for future reference, I should only use `var` when defining variables in scope, and always use `let` or `const` when defining variables in blocks?

Answer (score 1):

You can benefit event capturing & bubbling. Select the all of buttons' parent element then attach an event listener to this element. Then in the callback write `console.log(e.target)` so you can see which button actually clicked.